# Discord.Net -- How to make Bot Ping users with "@"

Tags: c#, tags, bots, discord, discord.net

I'm working on coding a bot that will retrieve an image based on search parameters. When the bot returns the message after the command, I want the bot to alert the user that sent the command with a ping. (the notification of a message using the "`@`" symbol in discord).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("@" + Context.Message.Author + "\n" + imageNode.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

I'm able to correctly grab the author of the command and it sends as it should--

Output in channel:

[image]

However, it's not actually sent as a tag, just plain text.

Is there a way to actually ding the user with a notification?

Comment: Can you select the answer below as the correct answer please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using `User.Mention`.

```
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Context.Message.Author.Mention + "\n" + imageNode.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

You can also just put their id in between `<@>`. For example, `"Hello <@1234>"`

Comment: thank you so, so much! It's been difficult to find up-to-date documentation on Discord.Net

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite things about C# 6 is that you can also use String Interpolation. Very useful in Discord.Net!

```
var id = Context.Message.Author.Id;
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"<@{id}> \n {imageNode.Attributes["src"].Value}";
```